# Working with Lightswitch, Silverlight & custom controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a screen with some data. Inside the screen I have two custom
controls (on the left and right side).

What I need to do is the following:

Bind some data from a database to some Controls in the first Custom control.
(fill a list, combobox etc, not so much the problem)

The user then can select an entry in the list, press a button -> the second CustomControl should now be made visible; request some data from the DB, based on the selection and dynamicly create and show a Chart.

So I know how to build the chart and build the Controls. But how can I access the Data
from the screen through code and access another CustomControl from within the first CustomControl?

**Edit:**

Things I found out.

1. Access control from screen

   `this.FindControl("yourControl");`
2. Do something with the control:

   `this.FindControl("yourControl").ControlAvailable += ( (o,e) => {
    YourControlType myControl = e.Control as YourControlType;
   });`
3. Access screen data

   ```
       IContentItem dataContext = this.DataContext as IContentItem;
       IScreenObject screen = dataContext.Screen;

       IScreenProperty prop = screen.Details.Properties["yourProperty"];

       VisualCollection<yourProperty> items = prop.Value as  VisualCollection<yourProperty>;
   ```
4. Show new screen

   `Application.Current.Details.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
       Application.Current.ShowGraphScreen(reportItem.BlockID));`

Maybe this will help someone.

Comment: Does this link help? [Custom Control Binding](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/lsextensibility/thread/394d7968-5210-441a-bf29-3da7001af07d)

Comment: +1 just for the little gems on how to access screen data. As custom controls now have to be in a separate library adding a reference to the generated `Application.common` of the client app, combined with your examples, was a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Filter query with a Parameter on the collection in the DB that you want the data from. Add this query to the screen and set the Parameter Binding to `FirstCustomControl`.

Drag the query onto the screen tree, change it to a chart, and check the binding as per Yann's link.

You would then need code similar to the following to show/hide the control:

```
partial void ScreenName_InitializeDataWorkspace(List<IDataService> saveChangesTo)
{
    this.FindControl("SecondCustomControl").IsVisible = False;
}

partial void ButtonName_Execute()
{
    this.FindControl("SecondCustomControl").IsVisible = True;
}
```

Since `SecondCustomControl` (I'm assuming this is the chart) is bound to the query and the query's parameter is bound to the value selected in the `FirstCustomControl`, the data gathering is all done in the background.